# Java and using method addAll for List<Character>

Tags: java

I have something simple, but can't solve. I just want to add one list of chars to another . It's working with `String` types. Why does it not work with `char`?

```
Character [] myChar={'a', 's', 'd','f', 't', 'i'};
List<Character> listChar= Arrays.asList(myChar);
Character[] newChar= new Character[listChar.size()];
List<Character> newlistChar= Arrays.asList(newChar);
Collections.fill(newlistChar, 'd');
output(newlistChar,"filled d");
Collections.addAll(listChar,newlistChar); // does not work
```

I tried to do something like casting the list, but still got an exception.

```
   ...((String)(listChar),(String)(newlistChar))
```

Even if I use something like this it still throws and exception. So how do I use addAll with `char`?

```
Collections.addAll(listChar,newlistChar.toArray(new Character[newlistChar.size()]));
```

Comment: Please, read ANY of given answers or copy WHOLE code which fixes your problem in my one. You've edited your question with another way of adding chars to fixed size arrays after 6 people said it doesn't work. Next code is your problem as well: `List<Character> listChar= Arrays.asList(myChar);`

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is `[homework]`, you should use a StringBuilder or just plain String.

```
// Using String
String myChars = "asdfti";
char[] ds = new char[mychars.length()];
Arrays.fill(ds, 'd');
myChars += new String(ds);
```

Comment: it's not homework  it's my  configurations of youtube videos ))

Comment: In that cause, don't use anything as low level as `char[]`, just use `String` or `string` (depending on the language) You should only do things the hard way if its homework and you have been told to. ;)

Answer (score 2):

- `asList`  returns a fixed size list, you can't add elements to it.
- `Collections.addAll` doesn't accept list as 2nd parameter

Use next:

```
    Character[] myChar = {'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 't', 'i'};
    List<Character> listChar = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(myChar));
    Character[] newChar = new Character[listChar.size()];
    Arrays.fill(newChar, 'd');
    Collections.addAll(listChar, newChar);
```

Comment: it's throw --> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Collections.addAll(Unknown Source)

Comment: pay attention to second line.

Answer (score 0):

`List` returned from [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(java.lang.Object%5b%5d)) has fixed size. You cannot add anything to it.

Instead, add both lists to new [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: it doesn't, you've used different code for String. If you don't agree, provide same code for String, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [javadoc of Collections.addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29)?

Its signature is

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c,
                                 T... elements)
```

This means that the second argument is a varargs. You may thus pass an array of Characters, or individual Character instances:

```
Collections.addAll(listChar, new Character[] {'a', 'b'});
Collections.addAll(listChar, Character.valueOf('a'), Character.valueOf('b'));
```

But a `List<Character>` is an invalid type for the second argument.

A good way to know is to actually read the compiler error message. Usually, they're much more informative than "it doesn't work".

And another problem is that the lists returned by `Arrays.asList()` have a fixed size. You can't add anything to them.

Answer (score 0):

Would this code snippet help?

```
    ArrayList<Character> myChar = new ArrayList<Character>();
    myChar.add('a');
    myChar.add('s'); 
    myChar.add('d');
    myChar.add('f'); 
    myChar.add('t'); 
    myChar.add('i');

    ArrayList<Character> newlistChar= new ArrayList<Character>();
    newlistChar.add('d');

    myChar.addAll(newlistChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

change the last line to

Collections.addAll(listChar, newlistChar.toArray(new Character[newlistChar.size()]));